# python callback in Fortran via ctypes

Tags: python, c, fortran, ctypes, intel

Consider this C-interoperable  Fortran subroutine which is called from Python and takes a Python callback function as input argument, then calls it,

```
module FortranFunc_mod

    ! C-interoperable interface for the python callback
    abstract interface
        function getSquare_proc( x ) result(xSquared) bind(C)
            use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_double
            real(c_double), intent(in)              :: x
            real(c_double)                          :: xSquared
        end function getSquare_proc
    end interface

contains

    subroutine fortranFunc( getSquareFromPython ) bind(C, name="fortranFunc")
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: fortranFunc
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_funptr, c_f_procpointer, c_double
        implicit none
        type(c_funptr), intent(in)          :: getSquareFromPython
        procedure(getSquare_proc), pointer  :: getSquare
        real(c_double)                      :: x = 2._c_double, xSquared

        ! associate the input C procedure pointer to a Fortran procedure pointer
        call c_f_procpointer(cptr=getSquareFromPython, fptr=getSquare)
        xSquared = getSquare(x)
        write(*,*) "xSquared = ", xSquared
    end subroutine fortranFunc

end module FortranFunc_mod
```

The Python function could be something like the following,

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes as ct

# import dll and define result type
ff = ct.CDLL('FortranFunc_mod')
ff.fortranFunc.restype = None

# define and decorate Python callback with propoer ctypes
@ct.CFUNCTYPE( ct.c_double, ct.c_double ) # result type, argument type
def getSquareFromPython(x): return np.double(x**2)

# call Fortran function
ff.fortranFunc( getSquareFromPython )
```

However, compiling this code with ifort (which is done successfully) and then running the Python code results in the following error,

```
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2b798bfb58b5> in <module>
     11
     12 # call Fortran function
---> 13 ff.fortranFunc( getSquareFromPython )

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

What am I missing in this simple example? Is there a need for an extra C-wrapper between Fortran and python code to define the callback prototype? If you could also provide the C equivalent code to call the Python function, that would also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue with your example is that `ff.fortranFunc` only has its *return* type specified, not its *argument* type. The Fortran subroutine `fortranFunc` has one input argument of `type(c_funptr)` and this should be reflected on the Python side too.

Exactly how to implement a solution, depends on whether you want to make changes only in Python, or are willing to make changes in the Fortran source too. I'll give an overview of both solutions:

#### Only make changes in Python

Below is an updated version of your Python test routine (I'm calling it `test.py`), with the following specific changes:

- specifying `ff.fortranFunc.argtypes`
- the `arg_type` is specified as a pointer to a `c_double` - how a scalar argument would be passed in C
- the callback function `getSquareFromPython` is also modified to reflect this `x[0]`

(For details on the last two points, see [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions) - the 2.7 version possibly explains this even clearer)

```py
import ctypes as ct

# callback function ctypes specification
return_type = ct.c_double
arg_type = ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)
func_spec = ct.CFUNCTYPE(return_type, arg_type)

# import dll and define result AND argument type
ff = ct.CDLL('FortranFunc_mod')
ff.fortranFunc.restype = None
ff.fortranFunc.argtypes = [ct.POINTER(func_spec),]

# decorate Python callback
@func_spec
def getSquareFromPython(x):
    return x[0]**2

# call Fortran function
ff.fortranFunc( getSquareFromPython )
```

#### Make changes in Python and Fortran

If you prefer to stay closer to your original Python implementation, that can also be made to work by making the following changes to `test.py`:

- change `fortranFunc`'s argument type: `arg_type = ct.c_double`
- change `getSquareFromPython`'s return value: `x**2`

However, since the callback function now expects a `c_double` as input argument (and not a pointer to one), you would have to change your Fortran abstract interface to reflect that, by adding the `value` attribute to the dummy argument `x`:

```
abstract interface
    function getSquare_proc( x ) result(xSquared) bind(C)
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_double
        real(c_double), intent(in), value       :: x
        real(c_double)                          :: xSquared
    end function getSquare_proc
end interface
```

#### Compile and run

Compiling and running either of the modified versions of the code, give me the following result with ifort on Windows (with appropriate changes in the compile command and library name it also works with gfortran on Linux and OS X):

```
> ifort /DLL FortranFunc_mod.f90 /o FortranFunc_mod.dll
...
> python test.py
 xSquared =    4.00000000000000
```

#### Note on the difference between the two cases

The difference between the two implementations is clearly reflected by looking at the dynamic type of `getSquareFromPython`'s argument `x` (it also explains the notation change necessary for the two alternatives). For the first alternative presented, you can add the statements on the left to `getSquareFromPython`, to get the results shown on the right:

```
print(type(x).__name__)                 :  LP_c_double
print(type(x.contents).__name__)        :  c_double
print(type(x.contents.value).__name__)  :  float
print(type(x[0]).__name__)              :  float
print(x.contents.value == x[0])         :  True
```

while for the second alternative:

```
print(type(x).__name__)                 :  float
```

Comment: You're welcome. An alternative could be to change argument type in `ctypes_wrapper` to `ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)` and then change your python function return value to `x[0]**2`, then you don't need to modify the fortran code at all. I'll update my answer to reflect this when i have time

Comment: that was the next on my to-do list, thanks for your answer before asking! very helpful.

Comment: So, here is my next question: how does Python indexing `x[0]` convert the pointer to a value? I have a feeling though that my question is flawed, and that flaw is actually my question if you see it there.

Comment: I've updated my question, hopefully explaining both situations more clearly. I've also suggested an edit to your question - adding the [ctypes] tag instead of [intel], hoping this may get you an even better explanation from an expert following that tag.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like Python indexing somehow dereferences the pointer. I would not be surprised if that was the case, as Python does a lot of things often, without telling the user.

Comment: Is it possible to have a code where the python function returns `x**2` and not `x[0]**2` ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, is that not the case in the 2nd alternative *make changes in Python and Fortran*?